# Changing several DIVs class with a form (select options) and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onselect

I would like to make the users of my website answer questions by selecting an option for each question. If they select the right answer, the paragraph they gave the right answer in gets green and they can continue to answer the following questions through the same procedure without reloading the current page.

That would work with "onClick" events but if the right answer is selected and then replaced by something else the DIV keeps the same newly added class. So that's why I would like to use onSelect, which doesn't work here...

Could anyone help me ? Thank you

```
<script language="javascript">

    function change_class1() {
        var p_l1 = document.getElementById("p_langue1");
        p_1.className = "point_langue";
    }

    function change_class2() {
        var p_l2 = document.getElementById("p_langue2");
        p_2.className = "point_langue";
    }

    function change_class3() {
        var p_l3 = document.getElementById("p_langue3");
        p_3.className = "point_langue";
    }

</script>>

<h3>QUESTIONS & ANSWERS</h3>

<div id="p_langue1">
    <p>Question 1</p>
    <select>
        <option>A</option>
        <option onselect="change_class1()">B</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="p_langue2">
    <p>Question 2</p>
    <select>
        <option onselect="change_class2()">A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="p_langue3">
    <p>Question 3</p>
    <select>
        <option onselect="change_class3()">A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use jQuery instead of pure javascript?

Comment: I suppose that user is not allowed to answer a question if all previous are not correct, right? Second question: how do you know if an answer is correct or not? Are correct answers stored in a database?

Comment: He is allowed to answer a question if all previous are not correct, and I already put a "onselect" to all the right answers. I'd just like to know what's wrong with the onSelect while onClick works :C

Comment: But @user2911849 you have to change the div color when the wrong answer is selected right? In that case, you have to handle the onchange event of select element.

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6 there is no `onSelect` event for `option`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2eeo02sz/)

```
 <h3>QUESTIONS & ANSWERS</h3>

<div id="p_langue1">
    <p>Question 1</p>
    <select onchange="change_class('p_langue1',this.value)">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="p_langue2">
    <p>Question 2</p>
    <select onchange="change_class('p_langue2',this.value)">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="p_langue3">
    <p>Question 3</p>
    <select onchange="change_class('p_langue3',this.value)">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
</div>

 function change_class(selectedId, answer) {
     var selectedValue = document.getElementById(selectedId);
     if (answer == 'A') {
         selectedValue.className = "point_langue";
     } else {
         selectedValue.className = "";
     }
 }

.point_langue {
    color :green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery you can handle the onchange event more easily for each select field as follows,

```
$('#p_langue1').on('change', function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();
    if(selectedOption === 'B') {
        $('#p_langue1').addClass('point_langue');
    } else {
        $('#p_langue1').removeClass('point_langue');
    }
});
```

otherwise you can set the 'onchange' event for select and in javascript,

```
function onSelectChange() {
    var selectedOption = document.getElementById("p_langue1").value;
    if(selectedOption === 'B') {
        document.getElementById("p_langue1").setAttribute('class','point_langue');
    } else {
        document.getElementById("p_langue1").removeAttribute('class','');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this option Vaibhav Katole. The real answers to the questions are not A or B, I wrote these letters to simplify my code. I guess I'll have to put values into the right answers' <option>, but then I don't know if your code with work